# Error deploying docpad DocPad site to Heroku

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, docpad

I was following along to a tutorial and downloaded the prebuilt site. Made minor changes on November 18, 2013 as shown in my [github commits](https://github.com/JGallardo/hipsterux/commits/master). And then pushed to Heroku but getting errors.

[image: heroku error screen]

This is the result that I got when I ran `heroku logs`

```
2013-11-18T20:17:28.227721+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-11-18T20:17:28.283130+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-11-18T20:26:28.114070+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=nodehipster.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-11-18T20:26:28.263173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nodehipster.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-11-18T20:26:28.571363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nodehipster.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-11-18T20:30:18.395751+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=nodehipster.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-11-18T20:34:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-11-18T20:34:44.265581+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-11-18T20:34:44.302566+00:00 heroku[api]: Add PATH config by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-11-18T20:34:44.333763+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-11-18T20:34:44.413127+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8fbd235 by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-11-18T20:34:44.432473+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2013-11-18T20:34:44+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-11-18T20:34:47.265386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node_modules/docpad/bin/docpad-server`
2013-11-18T20:34:49.200112+00:00 app[web.1]: info: Environment: development
2013-11-18T20:34:49.193219+00:00 app[web.1]: info: Welcome to DocPad v6.54.8 (global installation: /app/node_modules/docpad)
2013-11-18T20:34:49.195637+00:00 app[web.1]: info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
2013-11-18T20:34:49.197908+00:00 app[web.1]: info: Plugins: cleanurls, coffeescript, eco, ghpages, grunt, highlightjs, livereload, marked, nodesass, partials, related, sass, text
2013-11-18T20:34:49.337179+00:00 app[web.1]: info: DocPad listening to http://localhost:40142/ on directory /app/out
2013-11-18T20:34:49.381385+00:00 app[web.1]: info: LiveReload listening to new socket on channel /docpad-livereload
2013-11-18T20:34:49.394435+00:00 app[web.1]: info: Generating...
2013-11-18T20:34:50.953986+00:00 app[web.1]: warning:
2013-11-18T20:34:50.953986+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendering the extension "md" to "html" on "posts/inception-of-this-site.html.md" didn't do anything.
2013-11-18T20:34:50.953986+00:00 app[web.1]:   Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
2013-11-18T20:34:50.960356+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendering the extension "md" to "html" on "posts/my-project-brvtally.html.md" didn't do anything.
2013-11-18T20:34:50.960356+00:00 app[web.1]: warning:
2013-11-18T20:34:50.960356+00:00 app[web.1]:   Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
2013-11-18T20:34:51.581577+00:00 app[web.1]:     /app/node_modules/docpad-plugin-nodesass/node_modules/node-bourbon/assets/stylesheets/bourbon-deprecated-upcoming:7, in mixin `box-shadow`
2013-11-18T20:34:51.581577+00:00 app[web.1]:     /app/src/documents/styles/style.css.scss:48
2013-11-18T20:34:51.581577+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: box-shadow is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version release
2013-11-18T20:34:51.581577+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-11-18T20:34:51.595182+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendering the extension "md" to "html" on "posts/inception-of-this-site.html.md" didn't do anything.
2013-11-18T20:34:51.595182+00:00 app[web.1]: warning:
2013-11-18T20:34:51.595182+00:00 app[web.1]:   Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
2013-11-18T20:34:51.608794+00:00 app[web.1]: warning:
2013-11-18T20:34:51.608794+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendering the extension "md" to "html" on "posts/my-project-brvtally.html.md" didn't do anything.
2013-11-18T20:34:51.608794+00:00 app[web.1]:   Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
2013-11-18T20:34:52.071146+00:00 app[web.1]: SCSS does not appear to be available on your system
2013-11-18T20:34:52.071146+00:00 app[web.1]: warning: Something went wrong while rendering: styles/style.css.scss
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SassPlugin.render (/app/node_modules/docpad-plugin-sass/out/sass.plugin.js:96:25)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Task.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/out/lib/event-emitter-grouped.js:38:23)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.081587+00:00 app[web.1]: SCSS does not appear to be available on your system
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: SCSS does not appear to be available on your system
2013-11-18T20:34:52.081587+00:00 app[web.1]: warning: Something went wrong while rendering: styles/zurb-foundation.css.scss
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ambi (/app/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:23:18)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at b (domain.js:183:18)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Domain.run (domain.js:123:23)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fire (/app/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:159:23)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ambi (/app/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:23:18)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082978+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickFromSpinner (node.js:390:15)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Task.fire (/app/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:166:25)
2013-11-18T20:34:52.082835+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
2013-11-18T20:35:22.933177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/ host=nodehipster.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-11-18T20:34:49.543710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-11-18T20:38:47.093255+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/ host=nodehipster.herokuapp.com fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

While reading the [documentation from docpad](http://docpad.org/docs/deploy) on deploying to Heroku I did not notice that I needed to run `heroku config:add NODE_ENV=production` from the terminal. But still no success.

The logs mention http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering, which is just a conversation between people complaining about this issue. And someone suggests a plugin for windows (I am on a mac).

[image: plugin]

And then another person says that he solved this by adding `*.min.css` files to a folder called static.

[image: fixed with]

But where are those files in the first place, and where should I create this static file. and am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `sass` and `nodesass` plugins are installed, which will conflict with each other.

The `sass` pugin will not run on Heroku, unless you manually install sass via a custom buildpack yourself. The `nodesass` plugin should.

Try just uninstalling the sass plugin `docpad uninstall sass` and try the deploy again.